# Table View Not Updating After Reload and NSNotification

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, reloaddata

I use NSNotifications to call refreshChats when a user leaves a group chat. This updates User.current.groups (works correctly I've tested) so refreshChats should observe all the groups expect the group that the user just left. Tableview.reloadData() gets called after sorting the messages but I still see the group chat that I just left in the table view. I have to reopen the app after terminating to see the changes.

```
@objc func refreshChats(notification: NSNotification) {
    messages.removeAll()
    messagesDictionary.removeAll()
    for group in User.current.groups {
        observeGroupMessages(group: group)
    }
    observeUserMessages()
}
```

Comment: do you call reloadData() in mainThread ?

Comment: no. I only call it after I observe all the messages. Should I be doing it in mainThread for this case?

Comment: yes, call it in main thread

Comment: Didn't work for me. I also noticed if I leave a second group chat after leaving the first, the table view will then correctly not show the first one but still the second.